# Instance of 'PostgrestFilterBuilder<dynamic>' to bool

Tags: database, flutter, supabase

i'm working on a flutter app and supabase. I have a table with some information and one of the column is a bool type.

when I recall an information of that column, I receive *Instance of 'PostgrestFilterBuilder'* and not a true/false information.

the code i used is this:

```
autorizzazione = supabase.from('profili').select('autorized').textSearch('usernumber', matricola!)
```

I think I'm so wrong with that code.

**Update (31/12/2022)**

I tried some experiments and I found a part of solution: Future function asynced.

If I use a function like this:

```
    Future<Map<String, String>> _nameOfFunction(BuildContext context, String Input) async {
         var output = supabase.from('table').select('column1, column2').textSearch('column1', Input);
...other code here...
         return userinfo;
    }
```

I receive exactly what I want, because "userinfo" saved the info. But, if I recall that funcion in a `Widget build(BuildContext context) {}', that doesn't work. It returns *"Instance of 'Map<String, String>' "* and not the real output.

However, my problem is to recall that info stored in that table on supabase before create the SideBar and used it for enable or disable the buttons.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `.execute` or `.then` at the end.

Comment: After `textSearch()`, `.execute` is deprecate and `.then` is another thing *Register callbacks to be called when this future completes*, not what i need.

Comment: Use `execute` for now until you find a better solution.